# Getting IFrame contents using PuppeteerSharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I am trying to get content of all iframe contents on a page using PuppeteerSharp but when it hit an Advertisement Iframe it is hanging there forever without giving any error, it just waiting. You can use any website link which includes an advertisement iframe, for example, https://www.bbc.com/ You can see the code which is not working as I expected below. It does not have to be solved in PuppeteerSharp, any Puppeteer solution also is welcome.

```
        var iframes = await page.QuerySelectorAllAsync("iframe");
        if (iframes?.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var iframe in iframes)
            {
                var content = await iframe.ContentFrameAsync();
                var html = await content.GetContentAsync();
            }
        }
```

I tried also to loop the built-in "page.Frames" array but it gives the same result.